# how to modify response status code in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

using chrome.webRequest I can modify request or response headers, however I also need modify Response.statusCode, is it possible? I do not see anything in documentation.

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/webRequest/

I see something interesting here:
https://tweak-extension.com/blog/how-to-override-http-status-code#lets-override

It seems the request is not sent but a mock response has been applied but I'm not sure how.

Comment: It depends on the type of requests. If it's a `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` you can override their prototypes in [page context](/a/9517879) and override the returned data any way you want. If it's a built-in request made by the browser the only way to override the status code is chrome.debugger API and [Fetch](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Fetch) events+commands.

Comment: @wOxxOm I think the debugger API is the way to go, thanks!